# Grep in file with whole cat output

Tags: shell-script, grep

I search/try to write short script (for if loop) to do grep in file by whole cat output.

Already I tried

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
find -name 'xmlrpc.php' -execdir bash -c '
if [ -e ".htaccess" ] ; then
if grep -qxf /home/tstepien/Desktop/code/testing/addthat.txt .htaccess
then
        echo found
else
        (cat /home/tstepien/Desktop/code/testing/addthat.txt && cat .htaccess) > .htaccess.post && mv .htaccess.post .htaccess
fi
fi' {} \;
```

but it's "grepping" by all words in `addthat.txt`

example of `addthat.txt`

```bsh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /xmlrpc.php [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

.htaccess (before using script)

```
==========
here code
==========
```

.htaccess (after using script - so `if` statement will show "found" if it will be runned again and will not redo adding content of `addthat.txt`)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /xmlrpc.php [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
==========
here some code
==========
```

and it means that if in `.htaccess` there is text which is inside of `addthat.txt` then the contents of `addthat.txt` shouldn't be added to `.htaccess`.

Comment: What is `block.txt`? You don't seem to use that file anywhere. Do you mean `addthat.txt`? And what exactly are you trying to do? Your command is grepping for the entire contents of `addthat.txt`. Is that what you really want? Please [edit] your question and give us an example of both `addthat.txt` and `.htaccess` and what you want to happen after running your script.

Comment: ok I will edit - and yes I had block.txt but then I rearranged code and I forgot about that.

Comment: @terdon I've edited post to clearify

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I'm still confused about what you want exactly. Do you want to add _all_ lines from `addthat.txt` if _any_ lines are not already in `.htaccess`? Or do you only want to add those lines that are missing? Your previous grep command was doing something completely different. And what is the actual problem? I mean, what isn't working the way you want it to work?

Comment: before edit was bad grep - now after comments it's looks more like I want.
I want only pass `addthat.txt` to beginning of file IF it's not exist in beginning.

Comment: If what doesn't exist? _Any_ line from `addtaht.txt`? _All_ lines from `addthat.txt`? What if `.htaccess` contains `RewriteRule .* - [F,L]` does not contain `RewriteEngine On`? What should happen then? More importantly, _what is the problem now_? How is this failing?

Comment: Now it's not failing (what I see) but it's should have on first 4 lines that what's in `addthat.txt` - final `.htaccess` should have all 4 lines from `addthat.txt` on top - on bottom can repeats of `rewrite rule` etc (from CMS rules for example)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are looking for is close:

```
grep -q -e "$(cat addthat.txt)" .htaccess
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone wrote that answer here but now it's deleted.
And it works like charm.

```
grep -qxf /home/tstepien/Desktop/code/testing/addthat.txt .htaccess
```

> -q for quiet mode (only exit code)
>
> -f searching by provided file
>
> -x for searching by whole lines

Comment: Yes I removed it because it gives a wrong result. It only tells you if any line in addthat.txt is in .htaccess, not if the whole of addthat.txt in in .htaccess. And if you don't add a`-x` to match only whole lines a line with a single space in addthat.txt is pretty much guaranteed to trigger match.

Comment: yes - adding -X is good idea